# Async Await in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I have looked for similar issues here but cannot find one similar enough.
Using Ionic 4 with Angular 7 Typescript 3.16
I have several 'TimeSpan' values I need to get so have a function from the html like this:

```
<ion-input type="text" (click) =" getTypTime()" ....>
```

This click handler is like this:

```
getTypTime() { // Gets the typical time
  const currentTime = this.service.TimeToDoTypicalOrBestCase;
  this.getTime(currentTime).then( res => {
  console.log('GetTypTime result :');        // **3**
  console.log(res);
  });
}
```

The function to present the picker and get the result is like this:

```
async getTime(inputTime: TimeSpan) {
console.log(inputTime);             // **1**
const opts: PickerOptions = {
  buttons: [
        ...more stuff...
  ],
  columns: [
    {
      name: 'Hours',
        ...more stuff...
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Mins',
           ...more stuff...
    }
  ]
};
const picker = await this.pickerCtrl.create(opts);
console.log('Presenting picker');             // **2**
picker.present();
picker.onDidDismiss().then(() => {
  picker.getColumn('Hours').then( colh => {
    this.pickedTime.hours = colh.options[colh.selectedIndex].value;
    picker.getColumn('Mins').then( colm => {
    this.pickedTime.minutes = colm.options[colm.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(this.pickedTime);             // **4**
    return this.pickedTime.ToString();
    });
  });
 });
}
```

The log outputs:

```
00:30:00                       (This is a the top of the function **1** see code)
Presenting picker              (This is towards the end of the function **2**)
GetTypTime result : undefined  (This is in the CALLING function **3**)  
(The following line displayed after the dismiss **4**) 
TimeSpan {_seconds: 0, _minutes: 0, _hours: 0, _ days: 0, _milliseconds: 0, …}
```

The function is obviously returning before it has actually come back from the ondismiss of the picker, but I feel this should work. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong with it..?

I have changed this to move away from using await... before, it was like this:

```
  picker.onDidDismiss().then(async () => {
  let col = await picker.getColumn('Hours');
  this.pickedTime.hours = col.options[col.selectedIndex].value;
  col = await picker.getColumn('Mins');
  this.pickedTime.minutes = col.options[col.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(this.pickedTime);
  return this.pickedTime.ToString();
});
```

}

But that didnt work so I modified it to remove the awaits..
Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem but will confess to still not fully understanding the issue. However I have done it as an answer in case anyone else gets into a similar mess.

It being down to the difference between using async ... await or ...then( () => {}) to handle promises.
I come from a c# background so am pretty ok with async / await as it pretty much does what is says.
I have however found situations in TypeScript where I have had to use await AND combine it with .then( etc.).

Anyway, I did solve it by converting it to await all the way through and even adding it to the calling function.
Doing this:

```
const picker = await this.pickerCtrl.create(opts);
await picker.present();
await picker.onDidDismiss();
const colh = await picker.getColumn('Hours');
this.pickedTime.hours = colh.options[colh.selectedIndex].value;
const colm = await picker.getColumn('Mins');
this.pickedTime.minutes = colm.options[colm.selectedIndex].value;
return this.pickedTime.ToString();
```

solved the ordering issue, but was returning undefined.. or rather the calling function:

```
  getTypTime() { // Gets the typical time
    const currentTime = this.service.TimeToDoTypicalOrBestCase;
    this.getTime(currentTime).then( res => {
    console.log('GetTypTime result :');
    console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

showed undefined.
It was only when I modified it to this:

```
  async getTypTime() { // Gets the typical time
  const currentTime = this.service.TimeToDoTypicalOrBestCase;
  const res = await this.getTime(currentTime);
  console.log('GetTypTime result :');
  console.log(res);
```

}

that it all worked properly.

So thank you for those that did answer anyway.